# connect firebase authentication with realtime database from firebase

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Hello right now i created the signup and login page for authentication with ionic and firebase, but i have also a seperate profile page. My question is how can i connect the authentication with the realtimedatabase information like username, firstname and lastname.

```
signUp(email: string, password: string) {
    this.angularFireAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(() => {
      this.showToast('Account gemaakt graag je emailadres verifieren.');
      this.sendVerificationMail();
    })
      .catch(error => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        let errorMessage;
        switch (errorCode) {
          case 'auth/email-already-in-use':
            errorMessage = 'Dit emailadres bestaat al.';
            break;
          case 'auth/invalid-email':
            errorMessage = 'Dit emailadres is onjuist.';
            break;
        }
        this.presentAlert(errorMessage);
      });
  }

  signIn(email: string, password: string) {
    this.angularFireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(res => {
      if (res.user.emailVerified) {

      }
      else {
        this.showToast('email is niet geverifieerd.');
      }
    })
      .catch(error => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        let errorMessage;
        switch (errorCode) {
          case 'auth/user-not-found':
            errorMessage = 'Dit emailadres komt niet bekend voor.';
            break;
          case 'auth/user-disabled':
            errorMessage = 'Dit emailadres is geblokkeerd.';
            break;
          case 'auth/wrong-password':
            errorMessage = 'Het wachtwoord is onjuist.';
            break;
        }
        this.presentAlert(errorMessage);

      });
  }
//this is the profilepage code
update() {
    firebase.database().ref('users').push({
      gebruikersnaam: this.profileform.value.gebruikersnaam,
      voornaam: this.profileform.value.voornaam,
      achternaam: this.profileform.value.achternaam,
    });

  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I understand your question, but if you want to show information in another page (profile page) you can use "local storage"

Comment: It is better to add the suggestions as comment, not as an answer